# Jackson removes backslash from java string, why?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, escaping

I need to parse json using jackson:

```
String string = "{\"field\" : \" \\/ \"}";
JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(string);
String result = node.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

I expect this kind of output:

result == {"field":" \/ "}

But, I end up with:

result == {"field":" / "}

How can I receive output like this?

result == {"field":" \/ "}

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes are escapes in Java source itself, and in JSON. So you need to double them again

```java
String string = "{\"field\" : \" \\\\/ \"}";
```

Comment: But I will receive {"field":" \\/ "}, when I need {"field":" \/ "}

Comment: @Mr.Bere The string literal `"{\"field\" : \" \\\\/ \"}"` **is** the string with value `{"field" : " \\/ "}`. The back slash needs to be escaped once because of how JSON works, and then those two backslashes need to be escaped again because of the requirements of Java string literals.